# Removing \u0000 from nested JSON object before INSERTing into PostgreSQL

Tags: python, json, postgresql, unicode, sanitization

I am using Python to insert JSON objects into a PostgreSQL DB table.
The JSON nested are highly nested.
The strings in some of these JSON objects include '\u0000', which is an illegal character and UNICODE and must be sanitized before inserting into PG.

What would be the fastest way of doing that?

Answer (score 4):

Can you please see if this works for you as a parameter in your call to `execute()`?

```
>>> a = '\u0000'
>>> json.dumps(a).replace(r'\u0000', '')
'""'
>>>
```

The `r''` is for a raw string to help get around quoting problems.

Comment: Whoa! That did it. Thanks a zillion! I am going to read about `r''` now :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I've come up with.

```
def sanitize(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, str):
      return obj.replace('\u0000', '')
    if isinstance(obj, list):
      return [sanitize(item) for item in obj]
    if isinstance(obj, tuple):
      return tuple([sanitize(item) for item in obj])
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
      return {k:sanitize(v) for k,v in obj.items()}
    return obj
```

Is there a more elegant solution that I'm missing here?

Comment: How about `json.dumps(obj).replace('\u0000', '')` during the insert call to `execute()`?

Comment: Thank you! That was my first attempt. But dumps() \-escaped the character. I thought it's because the dumps() default for ensure_ascii is True, but also changing it to False didn't help.